# Expo build error - ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '\src\screens\node_modules\native-base\Fonts'

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting this error after upgrading the Expo SDK version to 33:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.\node_modules\native-base\Fonts'
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the Expo may have caused a conflict with the updated `@expo/vector-icons`. If the `native-base` module is deleted and is not reinstalled or the problem is not resolved,

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && expo start
```

Answer (score 1):

Expo loads fonts in a new way:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/

The below examples are based on both the examples from native-base and the expo docs.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase

You may need to run this first:

```
expo install expo-font
```

Then, in your code:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font'
```

and

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Using the import path of `native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf` did not work for me but using a relative path like below worked:

```
await Font.loadAsync({
    Roboto: require('../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
    Roboto_medium: require('../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf')
});
```

Here is a slightly more complete example:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isReady: false,
    };
    async componentDidMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto: require('../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
            Roboto_medium: require('../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf')
        });
        this.setState({ isReady: true });
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
            return ( <AppLoading />);
        }
        return <Navigator />;
    }
}
```